# Is using get() excessively in Java inefficient?

Tags: java, get, set

I was wondering whether it was more efficient to use get() excessively on an object or store the return of the get() in a variable and use that. For example, would it be more efficient to do this:

```
someObject.setColor(otherObject.getColor().r, otherObject.getColor().g, 
         otherObject.getColor().b);
```

or to store the it in a variable like this

```
Color color = otherObject.getColor();
someObject.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b);
```

Comment: Regardless of what's most efficient, I'm pretty sure choosing the least efficient will never be the primary bottleneck in anything you code.

Comment: I don't know about efficiency from a performance point of view, but from a readability (and typing) point of view, the second approach is better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1: you write the code as in example 1.

- the java runtime might or might not optimize the code (to turn it into something like your example 2)
- harder to read

Option 2: you write the code as in example 2.

- does not rely on optimizations by the java runtime
- easier to read

In my experience the runtime difference can be ignored (you can't measure the difference if not executed within a giant loop), but writing clean and understandable code is what counts.

Comment: Can you explain why in option two it does not rely on optimizations by the java run time?

Comment: @someFolk the possible optimization in option 1 is that the call to `otherObject.getColor()` is done only once, and the returned object is stored in a temporary variable. The java runtime might do that for you, or you do it explicitly for yourself as in option 2.

Answer (score 1):

In example#2

```
Color color = otherObject.getColor();
someObject.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b);
```

you are only creating a reference to the original object, so you are not using any considerable "extra" memory. plus it is more readable so +1 for example#2